# Contentful PHP SDK : How to retrieving localized embedded content in Content Renderer

Tags: php, contentful

Use of locale with CustomEmbedded block in CD CMS App.

I have the EmbeddedAssetBlock stuff working, but it only gets the default locale for the embedded item. All the rest of the content is translated properly, but the returned embedded entry is always the en version… why!? I don’t see a way of even specifying the locale for an EmbeddedAssetBlock in the php tools…

The embed object calls need the to know the active locale explicitly rather than it inheriting it automatically.

How can I edit CustomEmbeddedBlock.php Line : $entry=$node->getEntry();to fetch active locale.

This also doesn't work : $entry=$node->getEntry()->setLocale('en-US');

Error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Entry with ID was built using locale "en-GB", but now access using locale "en-US" is being attempted.")

Contentful\Delivery\Resource\LocalizedResource | Contentful CDA SDK for PHP

Any help would be appreciated…